# VB.net Mid as left operator special (strange?) behaviour

Tags: .net, vb.net

Today, while talking with my colleague, something odd came out of his mind.

A "secret" way to handle string coming from vb6, which was like:

```
 Dim strSomeString as String
 strSomeString = "i am phat" 
 Mid$(strSomeString, 6,4) = "hack"
```

This would put `i am hack` inside `strSomeString`.

While being surprised of such oddity being supported in vb6, I was totally blown when I read that [it is supported in VB.Net too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xz5s6003.aspx) (probably for compatibility with old code).

```
Dim TestString As String
' Initializes string.
TestString = "The dog jumps"
' Returns "The fox jumps".
Mid(TestString, 5, 3) = "fox"
' Returns "The cow jumps".
Mid(TestString, 5) = "cow"
' Returns "The cow jumpe".
Mid(TestString, 5) = "cow jumped over"
' Returns "The duc jumpe".
Mid(TestString, 5, 3) = "duck"
```

My question is: how is it technically working? What is `Mid` acting like in that particular situation? (method? function? extension method?)

Comment: In my time doing VB6, I never knew that this was remotely possible.  Please please tell me no one is doing this in .Net on purpose!

Comment: No worries. Doing so will asynchronously warn Microsoft, which will send bad people beating the crap out of the genius who did that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It gets translated to an MSIL call to this function in Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType

```
Public Shared Sub MidStmtStr ( _
    ByRef sDest As String, _
    StartPosition As Integer, _
    MaxInsertLength As Integer, _
    sInsert As String _
)
```

This compiler trick is purely for backwards compatibility. It's built into the compiler, so isn't the kind of trick you can implement yourself on your own types.

So

```
Mid(TestString, 5, 3) = "fox"
```

becomes

```
MidStmtStr(TestString, 5, 3, "fox")
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: @Alex: Glad to be of help mate.